# Sistema de amigos. PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

En una publicación anterior que publique la misma inquietud. Me informe mas y pude hacer el código mejor echo pero me sigue mostrando en mi propio perfil mi información. La pregunta seria la siguiente. ¿como hago para que no me muestre la información del id actual?.

Esta es mi db:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se esta visualizando el código por ahora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi estructura de código.

```
<?php
  $a_ = db_exec('query',"SELECT a.*, u.nick, u.avatar, u.portada FROM usuarios AS u LEFT JOIN amigos AS a ON (u.id = a.de) OR (a.para = u.id) WHERE a.id = '{$user['id']}' AND a.status = '1'");
  if (db_exec('num_rows', $a_) > 0) {
    foreach ($a_ as $ami) {
?>
<div class="user-preview landscape">Code de amigo</div>
<?php } } else { ?>
  <span class="no-ami">No tienes amigos</span>
<?php } ?>
```

En el código anterior la funcion db_exec me facilita al momento de hacer las consultas.
Creo que pueden entender el código bien. Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿podrias ser mas claro con el enunciado de la pregunta?, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres mostrar tanto los que **le han** solicitado amistad, como los que **le ha** solicitado amistad la consulta debería ser:

```
SELECT a.*, u.nick, u.avatar, u.portada 
  FROM usuarios u 
    LEFT JOIN amigos a 
      ON   ( a.de   = u.id and a.para = '{$user['id']}' )
        OR ( a.para = u.id and a.de   = '{$user['id']}' )
  WHERE a.status = '1'
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo. Ni te imaginas que problema me estaba costando.